# How to disable keyboard shortcut overlay that appears on super key hold in gnome desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-3, gnome-shell-extensions

I want to disable the keyboard shortcut overlay that appears on holding Super key in gnome desktop. How do I disable this?

I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 17.04.

I've searched and found the suggested solution(https://askubuntu.com/questions/93746/how-can-i-disable-the-windows-key-from-opening-the-activities-overview) not work for me. The suggested solution was to set:

`gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key 'Alt_R'`

but this didn't work :(
How does one disable it?